# POST request not working in Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cloud

I have a MEAN app deployed on Google Cloud (GAE). POST requests work locally but not in the cloud. Anything I need to do, specifically, to get this working on GAE?

GETs work fine.

Thanks.

ERROR that I get when hit from Postman:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <center>
            <h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1>
        </center>
        <hr>
        <center>nginx</center>
    </body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Not using NGINX locally, which is why it probably works fine.

Comment: Ha! Why would bad code work fine, locally?

Comment: a few reasons, bad directory reference, versioning, etc

Comment: What I meant was the app, running locally on my machine, works fine. After deploying the identical app to the cloud, it does not respond to POST requests. It does respond to GET requests, though.

Comment: I understand; however, we still need to see the code. We need to narrow the scope of the problem to arrive at a solution.

Answer (score 0):

What response do you get?

GAE is pretty strict and requires Content-Length on POST.

Answer (score 0):

I deployed same code on Heroku and it worked first shot. I'm sure there is some config issue between NGINX and Node on GAE, but I don't have the time to figure out someone else's issues.

Maybe when Google Cloud is a little more baked, I'll come back to it.